# How to create a expression of ClickHouse countIf function for linq2db?

Tags: countif, clickhouse, linq2db

How I can migrate clickhouse countIf function to linq2db?

Example:

from =>

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
    countIf(customer_id, active_month between 0 and 1) as active_month1
FROM myt_table
GROUP BY customer_id
```

to =>

```cs
from x in my_table
group x by x.customerId into g
select new {
    CustomerId = g.Key,
    ActiveMonth1 = Sql.CountIf(x, p => p.customerId, p => p.ActiveMonth.between(1, 6)) 
}
```

I tried this option but it has problems

```cs
from x in MyTable
group x by x.CustomerId into g
select new {
    CustomerId = g.Key,
    FirstMonthCount = g.Count(p => 1 >= p.ActiveMonth && p.ActiveMonth <= 6)
}
```

Comment: `countIf(customer_id, active_month between 0 and 1) as active_month1` BTW it calculates `number of rows` where condition is true AND customer_id is not null. I guess you need/meant `countIf(active_month between 0 and 1)`

Comment: You're right. I solved the problem by adding expression [Sql.Extension("countIf({predicate})", ServerSideOnly = true)] . Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Needs editing to add syntax highlighting: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workaround:

```cs
from x in MyTable
group x by x.CustomerId into g
select new 
{
    CustomerId = g.Key,
    FirstMonthCount = g.Sum(p => 1 >= p.ActiveMonth && p.ActiveMonth <= 6 ? 1 : 0)
}
```